# NodeJS setImmediate and private class method

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, event-loop, setimmediate

So, first time experimenting with `setImmediate`. It seems it can't run private class methods. Is that so? If yes, can someone explain to me why?

#### Doesn't work

> Private class method as argument to `setImmediate`. Throws `Callback must be a function. Received undefined`

```js
class TestPrivate {
    public start(): void {
        setImmediate(this.looper);
    }

    async looper(): Promise<void> {
        console.log(`${new Date().toLocaleString()}`);
        await sleep(500);
        setImmediate(this.looper);
    }
}

const testPrivate: TestPrivate = new TestPrivate();
testPrivate.start();
```

#### This does work

> Static class method as argument to `setImmediate`

```js
class TestStatic {
    public start(): void {
        setImmediate(TestStatic.looper);
    }

    static async looper(): Promise<void> {
        console.log(`${new Date().toLocaleString()}`);
        await sleep(500);
        setImmediate(TestStatic.looper);
    }
}

const testStatic: TestStatic = new TestStatic();
testStatic.start();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass `this.looper`, then the by the time the function is called, looper will no longer have a correct reference to `this`, so this breaks on the second iteration.

Solve this by using one of the following:

```
setImmediate(this.looper.bind(this));
setImmediate(() => this.looper());
```

Comment: Thanks @Evert. Both worked, though second one needs to be `called`: `this.looper()`.